# How do I install the newest version of the Software Center in 10.10?

Tags: 10.04, software-center

I was wondering if there was a way to upgrade the Ubuntu Software Center without upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10. I am content with 10.04 and have no wish to upgrade. However the new features of the Software Center intrigue me and I would like to check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A current updated version of Lucid holds v2.0.7 of the software center.

There is an old port (now unmaintained) available in a PPA :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:guido-iodice/guiodiclucid
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

However this repo also contains lots of other packages, so think twice before using this.
A few packages are still getting updated, but software-center is stuck at 2.1.7 (which is closest to the version maverick was distributed with (3.0.4).

Source : http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/06/changes-in-ubuntu-software-center-in.html

See the [Software center page on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/software-center)

**Update**: According to the [ubuntu archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-center/), the package 2.1.7 would indeed be a backport of the maverick version. I tried installing the maverick series (3.0) on a lucid machine but it has unmet dependencies.